# Unknown "dump" function error using Twig 1 and Codeigniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, twig, dump

I added Twig template engine to CodeIgniter 2 using this library:

https://github.com/dilantha/codeigniter-twig

Everything works except dum() function. Using dump troughs this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unknown "dump" function. Did you mean "var_dump", "debug_zval_dump", "xdebug_var_dump", "mysqli_dump_debug_info", "xdebug_dump_superglobals", "xdebug_dump_aggr_profiling_data"?

This is my Twig Template:

```
{{ dump() }}
```

And this is my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = ['title' => 'Title' ];
    $this->twig->display('dump.twig', $data);
}
```

CodeIgniter Version: 2.2.0

Twig Version: 1.35.4

Comment: It isn't enabled by default: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html

Answer (score 1):

This option is not enabled by default in version 1.and codeigniter-twig code missed this.
I added this code to Twig.php library and the problem solved:

```
    if ($debug) {
        $this->_twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
    }
```

I will report this to the author.